# How to sum the count value?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Table-1

Name.  Count
Xyz.        2
Yejs.       4
We.         6
```

I want the sum of count

Answer (score 1):

using Aggregate function you can get sum

for E.g

```
Select SUM(Count) from [Table-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, count(*) as mycount,
  (select count(*)
   from table_1) as totalcount
from
table_1
group by name
order by mycount
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ef83/5)